# Using Time Profiler to identify trouble areas in Table View

Tags: ios, uitableview, instruments

What are the steps I should follow for using Instruments' Time Profiler to identify trouble areas in a stuttering table view? I can't seem to find much online about this, unfortunately.

When I double click on the `UITableViewCell` line to pull up the code, it highlights 5 different image views in orange with 20% next to them. But I have a bunch of UILabels/UIButtons in there, too, and they aren't highlighted at all. Does that mean the labels/buttons just aren't taking up much processing time and I don't have to worry about them?